# Deny deletion after SFTP upload

Tags: sftp, inotify

I'd like to prevent users from deleting files they have uploaded to my sftp server.  I know I could set up a solution of my own using inotify/dnotify (or pam hook) and lsof which triggers a script to do something such as `chattr +i $filename` after a file is uploaded *and* closed. But I wonder if there is something already available as a feature or a solution already vetted and available of which I'm not aware.

The current setup is that I'm using openssh sftp and users are jailed upon connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at lsyncd(http://code.google.com/p/lsyncd/). It will provide inotify=>action part for your solution. It will look like this:

```
cat /etc/lsyncd.conf 
settings {
    logfile    = "/var/log/lsyncd.log",
    statusFile = "/var/run/lsyncd.status",
    nodaemon   = false,
    insist     = true,
}

-- config action
my_config = {
    delay = 10,
    maxProcesses = 1,
    onCreate  = "chattr +i -R /path/to/dir/*",
}

sync { my_config,
    source="/path/to/dir/",
}
-- EOF
```

you can change onCreate action for better logic, maybe run a script which will find uploaded files and set chattr +i.

Comment: you saw that I'm using openssh sftp, correct?  It's not an option for me to switch to vsftpd at this time.

Comment: Em...actually it's doesn't matter what daemon you use

Comment: I've removed word vsftpd for more clarity

Comment: Your example worked, and I was able to install it as an official debian package.  It's also available from the epel repository.  I did have to make some changes though.  /etc/lsyncd.conf didn't work.  When I opened the systemd unit startup script for lsyncd I saw that it expected its config file to be at `/etc/lsyncd/lsyncd.conf.lua` ...After tweaking that, things worked well!

Comment: Working example with lsyncd:

    sftp> put foo  
    Uploading foo to /upload/foo  
    foo  
    sftp> rm foo  
    Removing /upload/foo  
    Couldn't delete file: Permission denied

Comment: Glad that my solution helped you:)

Answer (score 1):

If you add your `sftp-server` umask option `-u` with parameter `0222`, new uploaded files will be created with above mentioned umask, which means they will not have write access for their files, so they will not be able to delete the files.

The line in your `sshd_config` will look something like this:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u 0222
```

Comment: Very nice.  I didn't see this in the man page for sshd_config because it's in the man page for sftp-server / internal-sftp.  Because I'm using a `Match Group ...` block for users of a certain group to make sure they're jailed, I think It will look like this, no?
`Match Group chrooted` ...other lines ... `ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0222`

Comment: using `ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0222` in the match block indeed created the file as `-r--r--r--` but I was able to delete the file.  I was also able to chmod the file to other perms.

Comment: Hmm. Chmod should be possible to disable using `-P` option to sftp-server. But if user is able to delete the file, then there is something wrong ...

Comment: if a user has mode 0444 on a file, deletion is still possible.

Comment: The mode of the file is not relevant to the deletion of the file. The deletion is authorized or not accordig to the write bit on the containing directory. A shell will probably give a warning or ask for confirmation when deleting a read-only file, but it is just a warning.